# VLC iOS compile not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

https://wiki.videolan.org/IOSCompile

I have Xcode 7 beta.

It come always this errors

```
ls: /Users/Man/Desktop/ios/ImportedSources/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-Simulator/x86_64/lib/vlc/plugins/lib*_plugin.a: No such file or directory
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure


#import <MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.h> file not found.
```

Comment: When an error is raised?

Comment: I give that in terminal:
git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc-ports/ios.git
                                                                     sudo gem install cocoapods pod install iOS sh compileVLCforiOS.sh -s

Comment: Open VLC for iOS.xcworkspace, then play button, now come this 3 erros. Can you help me plsssss

Comment: I need only running in iOS simulator.

Answer (score 1):

The git repository you tried to compile is out of date and no longer maintained. If you want to compile VLC for iOS yourself, you should get the latest source code tarball from our [iOS Download website](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html), which compiles just fine with Xcode 7 except for 1 minor issue in the GDrive SDK (just remove -werror from its GTL.xcodeproj).